# Multi user editing editor

Tags: php, synchronization, eclipse-plugin, collaboration

Me and a friend are working on some projects together and we are trying to synchronize everything what we have made. The problem is this synchronizing takes long and isn't fool proof. So we are in the search of a plugin for eclipse or another ide that can synchronize our files if we edit them..

A couple of years ago I've found some sort of plugin for eclipse that even enabled live editting, but I do not know the name anymore of this plugin.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source control is the way to go either with SVN or Team Foundation Server

Comment: It is not that we are working with a whole team on a project only with 2 people... Isn't svn or a team foundation server really necessary then ?

Comment: For a 2 person project I would just go with SVN.  It's the easiest to set up.  Using source control also offers a lot of other features such as going back through previous versions to see what has change, and resolving conflicts when 2 or more team members have changed the same code.

Comment: @Vince2doom I use SVN for nearly all my code, including projects I work on by myself. It's a habit you should definitely get into.

Comment: Hey, I'm working alone and I wouldn't want to type a single line of code without using a VCS! If you don't want to set up a server, maybe some DVCS like Mercurial, Git or Bazaar (which I personally use) could be the right thing. Depends on your working style and how often you need to synchronize...

Answer (score 0):

Use SVN. It has some quirks that can be annoying when you're working with lots of guys on lots of different braches, but as long as it's just a handful of guys working on the same code, it's great.

You can use the TortoiseSVN tool that integrates with Windows Explorer. Works quite nifty.